# Global symbols becoming local at link

Tags: c++, linker, dynamic-loading

I am having an issue with my global symbols. I have a class which is compiled with default visibility (the rest of the code is hidden) and no-inline. The executable is being linked with the -E flag as well. This class is called from a library that is loaded by dlopen; so its symbols need to be GLOBAL.

When I look at the .o file, things look ok:
   FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT

However in the final binary, same function turns into this:
   FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT

I think gc-sections is causing this and I cannot afford not to use it. Is there any way to tell gc-sections to ignore the public APIs?

Comment: You have not supplied enough info to answer your question. Pieces missing: which linker (gold or ld), which version, what is the linker command line, are there linker scripts involved, and if so, what do they contain?

Comment: At this point I believe it is a linker bug. There are multiple gc-sections related bugs in binutils bugzilla as well; and I think I am hitting one of them. I have tried the same link line with a very recent toolchain version and it worked the way I expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

> However in the final binary, same function turns into this: FUNC LOCAL DEFAULT

This is most likely happening because you have something on the linker command line that tells the linker to do that. Perhaps you have a linker version script that does this?

> I think gc-sections is causing this

That guess is very unlikely.